# Non-authoritative answer: *** Can't find xxxxxx.yyy: No answer

Tags: networking, dns, centos, nslookup

I installed `bind` on a CentOS 6 server for configuring a DNS zone for defining a domain. My `/etc/named.conf` is this:

```
options {
        # listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; };
        listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
        directory       "/var/named";
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
        allow-query     { any; };
        recursion no;

        dnssec-enable yes;
        dnssec-validation yes;
        dnssec-lookaside auto;

        /* Path to ISC DLV key */
        bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";

        managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
};

logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};

zone "." IN {
        type hint;
        file "named.ca";
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";

zone "xxxxxx.yyy" IN {
        type master;
        file "xxxxxx.yyy.zone";
        allow-update {none;};
};
```

and my zone configuration file (`/var/named/xxxxxx.yyy.zone`) based on [TLDP](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/DNS-HOWTO-7.html)  is:

```
$TTL 86400
@   IN  SOA     ns1.xxxxxx.yyy. root.xxxxxx.yyy. (
        2014011001  ;Serial
        3600        ;Refresh
        1800        ;Retry
        604800      ;Expire
        86400       ;Minimum TTL
)
@    IN  NS       ns1.xxxxxx.yyy.
@    IN  NS       ns2.xxxxxx.yyy.
ns1     IN  A    aaa.bbb.cc.ddd
ns2     IN  A    aaa.bbb.cc.ddd
```

I set nameserver of domain to `ns1.xxxxxx.yyy` and `ns2.xxxxxx.yyy` and i can get this nameserver on whois:

```
meysam@freedom:~$ whois xxxxxx.yyy
// blah blah blah
% Information related to 'xxxxxx.yyy'


domain:     xxxxxx.yyy
ascii:      xxxxxx.yyy
// blah blah blah
nserver:    ns1.xxxxxx.yyy
nserver:    ns2.xxxxxx.yyy
```

but when i ping domain, it return unknown host error:

```
meysam@freedom:~$ ping xxxxxx.yyy
ping: unknown host xxxxxx.yyy
```

also output of `nslookup` is similar:

```
meysam@freedom:~$ nslookup xxxxxx.yyy
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find yyyyyy.xxx: No answer
```

For more information, i append output of `dig` command:

```
meysam@freedom:~$ dig xxxxxx.yyy

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.5-Ubuntu <<>> xxxxxx.yyy
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 57346
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;xxxxxx.yyy.            IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
xxxxxx.yyy.     6606    IN  SOA ns1.xxxxxx.yyy. root.xxxxxx.yyy. 2014011001 3600 1800 604800 86400

;; Query time: 123 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1)
;; WHEN: Fri Dec 25 20:57:36 IRST 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 87
```

What's the problem? How can i fix this error?

Any guide is welcome.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears you are querying for an A record, when none is defined for the root of the domain.

Try adding one in your zone file.

```
@     IN  A    aaa.bbb.cc.ddd
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, try to check whether your address is resolved this way or not. `ns.awsdns.net` is your Name Server

> nslookup mydomain.com ns.awsdns.net

If the domain reloved this way, then follow these steps :

```
sudo mv /etc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf_orig
sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
sudo vim /etc/resolv.conf
```

edit and put this line within the resolv.conf and exit(8.8.8.8 is google DNS)

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

and finally, restart the network service

```
sudo service networking restart
```